# Injecting Symfony Serializer instantiates all Normalizers, failing if logged out

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Symfony application using the Serializer component a lot. Most Normalizers need access to the current User and therefor get `TokenStorageInterface` injected. This works quite well, until I inject the `SerializerInterface` into a controller where there is no current User (public pages, e.g. the login-form). Calling getters on the User object like `$this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser()->getUsername()` leads to the error message "Call to a member function getUsername() on string". That message is correct, as `getUser()` returns a string, if no actual user is logged in.

Turns out that the Serializer instantiates all Normalizers so that the missing User gets a problem.

What am I missing? How can I inject the Serializer service without initializing all Normalizers?

Comment: Are these your normalizers and are they calling getUsername() in the constructor?

Comment: @Cerad Yes, those are my own Normalizers. I could change them to not initialize completely inside the constructor (they load a UserSettings object, which is used to customize the serialized objects). So they could load just the user and at every use, the methods could get the settings from the User object. But before I change that, I wanted to ask, if I am missing something. And isn't that a performance issue if all Normalizers are initialized on every request?

Comment: I have not used the serializer much.  The normalizers get injected when the serializer is instantiated so there I don't think there is much you can do about that.  I suppose you could look into proxy services.  But as a rule I don't expect making a few more objects will really slow things down.  Maybe do some profiling.